# Shorter PHP Script

Tags: php, sql, loops, mysqli

I need you to help me shorten this code. It works perfectly and everything. So I need not only a shorter way, but one that works just like this one does. I'm sort of new to PHP and I know there must be a shorter way to put this script. Here it is:

```
<?php $sqlMS = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '1'";
$queryMS = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS);
    $AdvisoryMS = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS);


$sqlMS2 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '2'";
$queryMS2 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS2);
    $AdvisoryMS2 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS2);

$sqlMS3 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '3'";
$queryMS3 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS3);
    $AdvisoryMS3 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS3);

$sqlMS4 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '4'";
$queryMS4 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS4);
    $AdvisoryMS4 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS4);

$sqlMS5 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '5'";
$queryMS5 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS5);
    $AdvisoryMS5 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS5);

$sqlMS6 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '6'";
$queryMS6 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS6);
    $AdvisoryMS6 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS6);


$sqlMS7 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '7'";
$queryMS7 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS7);
    $AdvisoryMS7 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS7);


$sqlMS8 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '8'";
$queryMS8 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS8);
    $AdvisoryMS8 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS8);


$sqlMS9 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '9'";
$queryMS9 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS9);
    $AdvisoryMS9 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS9);


$sqlMS10 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '10'";
$queryMS10 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS10);
    $AdvisoryMS10 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS10);


$sqlMS11 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '11'";
$queryMS11 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS11);
    $AdvisoryMS11 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS11);


$sqlMS12 = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '12'";
$queryMS12 = mysqli_query($connection ,$sqlMS12);
    $AdvisoryMS12 = mysqli_num_rows($queryMS12);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://php.net/array  http://php.net/for

Comment: I admit, I laughed :-) But not at you!

Comment: HAHAHA hey you gotta learn something new sometime right? :)

Comment: @Quentin thanks i'm new to stackoverflow as well, so i didnt know about the code review. But now i do, Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vastly improve the efficiency of that code by using a single query:

```
$query = "SELECT MONTH(Date_Entered) AS month, COUNT(*) AS total FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid GROUP BY MONTH(Date_Entered)";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $AdvisoryMS[$row['month'] = $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: Even better if you only need the totals...

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Visits WHERE Company_ID = $cid AND MONTH(Date_Entered) = '$i'";
$query = mysqli_query($connection ,$sql);
$AdvisoryMS[$i] = mysqli_num_rows($query);

}
```

This uses a for loop to loop `$i` through 1-12 and puts the number of rows in an array rather than 12 separate variables.  For each result you access them through `$AdvisoryMS[1-12]`

Comment: haha bingo!! thanks mann :D

Comment: Giving the OP what he wants without actually helping him isn't really the answer. It might do what he wants, but didn't teach him anything.

Comment: well.. the code did help me understand what to do in this situation and why. I learned something new.

Comment: I'm resisting the urge to downvote, but I agree with Anyone - offering the answer without encouraging some prior effort does not help people discover answers from their own attempts.